Build Failure and App Crash After Adding @react-native-voice/voice in React Native 0.75 During Version Upgrade
I am currently upgrading a React Native project from version 0.68 to 0.75. While I have successfully updated all other packages, I am facing issues with the @react-native-voice/voice.
The app works perfectly when this package is removed, but as soon as I add it back, the build fails and the app crashes. I've tried following the official documentation and checked for compatibility, but I haven't been able to resolve the issue.
Observed Issue(complete log):
> react-native run-android

(node:95592) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
info Installing the app...

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_app
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at F:\ZURU\SmartHomeApp\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:firebase.bom using default value: 33.5.1
:react-native-firebase_app:play.play-services-auth using default value: 21.2.0
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at F:\ZURU\SmartHomeApp\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app:version set from package.json: 21.6.1 (21,6,1 - 21006001)
:react-native-firebase_app:android.compileSdk using custom value: 35
:react-native-firebase_app:android.targetSdk using custom value: 34
:react-native-firebase_app:android.minSdk using custom value: 24
:react-native-firebase_app:reactNativeAndroidDir F:\ZURU\SmartHomeApp\node_modules\react-native\android

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_auth
:react-native-firebase_auth package.json found at F:\ZURU\SmartHomeApp\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\auth\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at F:\ZURU\SmartHomeApp\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_auth:firebase.bom using default value: 33.5.1
:react-native-firebase_auth package.json found at F:\ZURU\SmartHomeApp\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\auth\package.json
:react-native-firebase_auth:version set from package.json: 21.6.1 (21,6,1 - 21006001)
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.compileSdk using custom value: 35
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.targetSdk using custom value: 34
:react-native-firebase_auth:android.minSdk using custom value: 24
:react-native-firebase_auth:reactNativeAndroidDir F:\ZURU\SmartHomeApp\node_modules\react-native\android       

> Configure project :react-native-firebase_crashlytics
:react-native-firebase_crashlytics package.json found at F:\ZURU\SmartHomeApp\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\crashlytics\package.json
:react-native-firebase_app package.json found at F:\ZURU\SmartHomeApp\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\app\package.json
:react-native-firebase_crashlytics:firebase.bom using default value: 33.5.1
:react-native-firebase_crashlytics package.json found at F:\ZURU\SmartHomeApp\node_modules\@react-native-firebase\crashlytics\package.json
:react-native-firebase_crashlytics:version set from package.json: 21.6.1 (21,6,1 - 21006001)
:react-native-firebase_crashlytics:android.compileSdk using custom value: 35
:react-native-firebase_crashlytics:android.targetSdk using custom value: 34
:react-native-firebase_crashlytics:android.minSdk using custom value: 24
:react-native-firebase_crashlytics:reactNativeAndroidDir F:\ZURU\SmartHomeApp\node_modules\react-native\android

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
Android gradle plugin: 8.6.0
Gradle: 8.7

> Task :react-native-voice_voice:packageDebugResources FAILED

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
137 actionable tasks: 5 executed, 132 up-to-date
                                                                                                               
info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running npx react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem was found with the configuration of task ':react-native-voice_voice:packageDebugResources' (type 'MergeResources').
  - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'F:\ZURU\SmartHomeApp\node_modules\@react-native-voice\voice\android\build\generated\res\resValues\debug'.

    Reason: Task ':react-native-voice_voice:packageDebugResources' uses this output of task ':@react-native-voice_voice:generateDebugResValues' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed.

    Possible solutions:
      1. Declare task ':@react-native-voice_voice:generateDebugResValues' as an input of ':react-native-voice_voice:packageDebugResources'.
      2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':@react-native-voice_voice:generateDebugResValues' from ':react-native-voice_voice:packageDebugResources' using Task#dependsOn.
      3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':@react-native-voice_voice:generateDebugResValues' from ':react-native-voice_voice:packageDebugResources' using Task#mustRunAfter.

    For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency in the Gradle documentation.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.

BUILD FAILED in 2s
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: A problem was found with the configuration of task ':react-native-voice_voice:packageDebugResources' (type 'MergeResources'). - Gradle detected a problem with the following location: 'F:\ZURU\SmartHomeApp\node_modules\@react-native-voice\voice\android\build\generated\res\resValues\debug'. Reason: Task ':react-native-voice_voice:packageDebugResources' uses this output of task ':@react-native-voice_voice:generateDebugResValues' without declaring an explicit or implicit dependency. This can lead to incorrect results being produced, depending on what order the tasks are executed. Possible solutions: 1. Declare task ':@react-native-voice_voice:generateDebugResValues' as an input of ':react-native-voice_voice:packageDebugResources'. 2. Declare an explicit dependency on ':@react-native-voice_voice:generateDebugResValues' from ':react-native-voice_voice:packageDebugResources' using Task#dependsOn. 3. Declare an explicit dependency on ':@react-native-voice_voice:generateDebugResValues' from ':react-native-voice_voice:packageDebugResources' using Task#mustRunAfter. For more information, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.7/userguide/validation_problems.html#implicit_dependency in the Gradle documentation. * Try: > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BUILD FAILED in 2s.

What I've Tried:

Checked the AndroidManifest.xml for misconfiguration.
Verified Gradle versions (8.7) and Android Gradle Plugin compatibility (8.6.0).
Removed and reinstalled the package.
Confirmed that other dependencies work fine.

Environment:

React Native Version: 0.75.4
@react-native-voice/voice Version: Latest (as of Dec 2024)
Gradle Version: 8.7
Android Gradle Plugin: 8.6.0
Node.js Version: 22.12.0
OS: Windows 11


I suspect the issue might be related to Gradle task dependencies or Android SDK/NDK compatibility, but I’m not sure how to resolve it. If anyone has successfully integrated @react-native-voice/voice in React Native 0.75, I’d appreciate your insights or solutions.
